# After term not significant difference-in-differences

Tags: inference, difference-in-difference, interpretation

I ran a difference-in-differences model and I have an interpretation issue. My difference between treated and control is not significant before and after. In the same time, my interaction term is significant. How should I interpret these results? Given that the difference is not significant after does it mean I cannot make any conclusions?

Comment: If the interaction term is significant then you interpret that, interpreting main effects is no longer relevant at this point.

Comment: Could you add your model in the Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference-in-difference equation is:
$$Y_{i,t} = \beta_0 1(i \in treated) + \gamma_t T_t +  \delta 1(i \in treated)  * T2 +\epsilon_{i,t} $$

where $1(i \in treated) $ is the group specific effect, $T_t$ are the time fixed-effects, and T2 is the dummy for all the time periods of the treatments; hence $\delta$, the coefficient in front of the interaction term, is the coefficient of interest.

If I understand well, the coefficient in front of G2 is non significant. It means that, outside of the period of interest, there is no significant difference between your treated and control. This is neither necessary nor sufficient, but it is encouraging regarding the fact that your control group is a good control group.

What matters for your research question is whether $\delta$ is significant.

Comment: Based on the model you gave, could you write 4 $E(Y)$ for 4 different combinations of treatment and time, i.e., (treatment, time 0), (treatment, time 1), (control, time 0) and (control, time 1)?

Comment: (control, time 0): $\gamma_0$
(control, time 7): $\gamma_7$ (let us say that treatment start for instance at time 7.
(treatment, time0): $\beta_0 + \gamma_0$ 
(treatment, time 7): $\beta_0 + \gamma_7 + \delta$